# FirebaseFirestoreSwift won't install (CocoaPods)

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

I'm trying to load FirebaseFirestoreSwift and I'm getting the error message:

```
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseFirestore":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    FirebaseFirestore (= 7.0.0, ~> 7.0.0)

  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Firestore was resolved to 7.0.0, which depends on
      FirebaseFirestore (~> 7.0.0)

    FirebaseFirestore

    FirebaseFirestoreSwift was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
      FirebaseFirestore (>= 1.6.1, ~> 1.6)
```

My Podfile has:

```
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
```

All the other pods have loaded fine. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Change to `pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '> 7.0-beta'`

Staring with the 7.0.0 release, Firebase is now indicating beta status with a version tag instead of a `0` major version. More details in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios).

Answer (score 6):

It's in the Beta phase and to fetch it you need to specify its version and as per  firebase/cocoapod document it's in **Beta 8.3.0** so you can try the below pod.

> You want to add pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '8.3.0-beta' similar to
> the following to your Podfile:

```
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '8.3.0-beta'
end
```

Then run a `pod install` inside your terminal, or from CocoaPods.app.

Alternatively to give it a test run, run the command:

```
pod try FirebaseFirestoreSwift
```

Hope this will helps to get it the right pod version.

Answer (score 3):

Always try to get the name of Pod from `cocoapods` website

```
pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '8.1.0-beta'
```

Answer (score 0):

in my Case Just Setup :
pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '9.2.0-beta'