# Cannot compile iOS app after installing firebase pods

Tags: xcode, firebase, swiftui, cocoapods

I've been struggling with this for days, desperately trying to find a solution online. Nothing works.
Here's the situation, I'll give all the elements I can, if something more is necessary, please let me know. I really don't know from what angle to take this.

1. I'm on a MacBook air M1. I'm running Xcode with Rosetta.
2. I want to use firebase. It doesn't matter if I install my pods using arch -x86_64 pod install or just 'pod install', I'll get the compile errors
3. My build settings look like the screenshot below (for the app, and for the pods)
4. Screenshots below also: the list of compile errors I'm getting. I can post a more detailed one if necessary, it's a huge list.

Build settings have something to do with some issues that people have

[app build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnbNG.png)

[pod build settings default (that I manually change to iOS each time)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYcPi.png)

[error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyZle.jpg)

Here's my podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Animals' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
 use_frameworks!

   pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

 # Optionally, include the Swift extensions if you're using Swift.
   pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'


  # Pods for Animals

end
```

my podfile.lock

```
PODS:
  - abseil/algorithm (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/algorithm/algorithm (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/algorithm/container (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/algorithm/algorithm (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/algorithm/container (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/algorithm/algorithm
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/base (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/atomic_hook (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/base (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/base_internal (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/bits (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/config (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/core_headers (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/dynamic_annotations (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/endian (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/errno_saver (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/exponential_biased (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/log_severity (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/malloc_internal (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/periodic_sampler (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/pretty_function (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/spinlock_wait (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/throw_delegate (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/base/atomic_hook (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/base (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/atomic_hook
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/dynamic_annotations
    - abseil/base/log_severity
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
    - abseil/base/spinlock_wait
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/base/base_internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/base/bits (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/config (0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/base/core_headers (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/base/dynamic_annotations (0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/base/endian (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/errno_saver (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/base/exponential_biased (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/log_severity (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/malloc_internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/dynamic_annotations
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
  - abseil/base/periodic_sampler (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/exponential_biased
  - abseil/base/pretty_function (0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/atomic_hook
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/log_severity
  - abseil/base/spinlock_wait (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/errno_saver
  - abseil/base/throw_delegate (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
  - abseil/container/compressed_tuple (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/utility/utility
  - abseil/container/inlined_vector (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/algorithm/algorithm
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/throw_delegate
    - abseil/container/inlined_vector_internal
    - abseil/memory/memory
  - abseil/container/inlined_vector_internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/container/compressed_tuple
    - abseil/memory/memory
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/types/span
  - abseil/memory (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/memory/memory (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/memory/memory (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/meta (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/meta/type_traits (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/meta/type_traits (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/numeric/int128 (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/strings/internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/endian
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/strings/str_format (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/strings/str_format_internal
  - abseil/strings/str_format_internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/numeric/int128
    - abseil/strings/strings
    - abseil/types/span
  - abseil/strings/strings (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base
    - abseil/base/bits
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/endian
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
    - abseil/base/throw_delegate
    - abseil/memory/memory
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/numeric/int128
    - abseil/strings/internal
  - abseil/time (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/time/internal (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/time/time (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/time/internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/time/internal/cctz (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/civil_time (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/time_zone (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/time/internal/cctz/civil_time (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/time/internal/cctz/time_zone (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/civil_time
  - abseil/time/time (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
    - abseil/numeric/int128
    - abseil/strings/strings
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/civil_time
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/time_zone
  - abseil/types (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/types/any (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/bad_any_cast (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/bad_any_cast_impl (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/bad_optional_access (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/bad_variant_access (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/compare (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/optional (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/span (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/variant (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/types/any (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/types/bad_any_cast
    - abseil/utility/utility
  - abseil/types/bad_any_cast (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/types/bad_any_cast_impl
  - abseil/types/bad_any_cast_impl (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
  - abseil/types/bad_optional_access (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
  - abseil/types/bad_variant_access (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
  - abseil/types/compare (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/types/optional (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/memory/memory
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/types/bad_optional_access
    - abseil/utility/utility
  - abseil/types/span (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/algorithm/algorithm
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/throw_delegate
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/types/variant (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/types/bad_variant_access
    - abseil/utility/utility
  - abseil/utility/utility (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.7):
    - BoringSSL-GRPC/Implementation (= 0.0.7)
    - BoringSSL-GRPC/Interface (= 0.0.7)
  - BoringSSL-GRPC/Implementation (0.0.7):
    - BoringSSL-GRPC/Interface (= 0.0.7)
  - BoringSSL-GRPC/Interface (0.0.7)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (6.34.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 6.10.4)
  - Firebase/Firestore (6.34.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseFirestore (~> 1.19.0)
  - FirebaseCore (6.10.4):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 1.6)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.7)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.7.0):
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 7.4)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.7)
    - nanopb (~> 1.30906.0)
  - FirebaseFirestore (1.19.0):
    - abseil/algorithm (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/memory (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/meta (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/strings/strings (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/time (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types (= 0.20200225.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.10)
    - "gRPC-C++ (~> 1.28.0)"
    - leveldb-library (~> 1.22)
    - nanopb (~> 1.30906.0)
  - FirebaseFirestoreSwift (0.4.0):
    - FirebaseFirestore (>= 1.6.1, ~> 1.6)
  - GoogleDataTransport (7.5.1):
    - nanopb (~> 1.30906.0)
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (6.7.2):
    - PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (6.7.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - "gRPC-C++ (1.28.2)":
    - "gRPC-C++/Implementation (= 1.28.2)"
    - "gRPC-C++/Interface (= 1.28.2)"
  - "gRPC-C++/Implementation (1.28.2)":
    - abseil/container/inlined_vector (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/memory/memory (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/strings/str_format (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/strings/strings (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/optional (= 0.20200225.0)
    - "gRPC-C++/Interface (= 1.28.2)"
    - gRPC-Core (= 1.28.2)
  - "gRPC-C++/Interface (1.28.2)"
  - gRPC-Core (1.28.2):
    - gRPC-Core/Implementation (= 1.28.2)
    - gRPC-Core/Interface (= 1.28.2)
  - gRPC-Core/Implementation (1.28.2):
    - abseil/container/inlined_vector (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/memory/memory (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/strings/str_format (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/strings/strings (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/optional (= 0.20200225.0)
    - BoringSSL-GRPC (= 0.0.7)
    - gRPC-Core/Interface (= 1.28.2)
  - gRPC-Core/Interface (1.28.2)
  - leveldb-library (1.22.1)
  - nanopb (1.30906.0):
    - nanopb/decode (= 1.30906.0)
    - nanopb/encode (= 1.30906.0)
  - nanopb/decode (1.30906.0)
  - nanopb/encode (1.30906.0)
  - PromisesObjC (1.2.12)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - Firebase/Firestore
  - FirebaseFirestoreSwift

SPEC REPOS:
  trunk:
    - abseil
    - BoringSSL-GRPC
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
    - FirebaseFirestore
    - FirebaseFirestoreSwift
    - GoogleDataTransport
    - GoogleUtilities
    - "gRPC-C++"
    - gRPC-Core
    - leveldb-library
    - nanopb
    - PromisesObjC

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  abseil: 6c8eb7892aefa08d929b39f9bb108e5367e3228f
  BoringSSL-GRPC: 8edf627ee524575e2f8d19d56f068b448eea3879
  Firebase: c23a36d9e4cdf7877dfcba8dd0c58add66358999
  FirebaseCore: d3a978a3cfa3240bf7e4ba7d137fdf5b22b628ec
  FirebaseCoreDiagnostics: 770ac5958e1372ce67959ae4b4f31d8e127c3ac1
  FirebaseFirestore: 9b2f1b9b9a6f2f0b6fb7484b9e32ab7e39243554
  FirebaseFirestoreSwift: 2c46dbc1156db97dc4f6dd798d4f5b57b9c7fab6
  GoogleDataTransport: f56af7caa4ed338dc8e138a5d7c5973e66440833
  GoogleUtilities: 7f2f5a07f888cdb145101d6042bc4422f57e70b3
  "gRPC-C++": 13d8ccef97d5c3c441b7e3c529ef28ebee86fad2
  gRPC-Core: 4afa11bfbedf7cdecd04de535a9e046893404ed5
  leveldb-library: 50c7b45cbd7bf543c81a468fe557a16ae3db8729
  nanopb: 59317e09cf1f1a0af72f12af412d54edf52603fc
  PromisesObjC: 3113f7f76903778cf4a0586bd1ab89329a0b7b97

PODFILE CHECKSUM: d1d0b6cce35a3ff7c25fd74111dc008969a9f275

COCOAPODS: 1.10.1
```

Thank you for your help...

Comment: You posted a screen shot that says there are build errors but you didn't show us _even one_ of those errors.

Comment: You're right, sorry.
https://imgur.com/vDY2rkF
https://imgur.com/GsljKVO
https://imgur.com/NY1uKwA
the list is long, it just keeps going.
https://imgur.com/bx2mtXc
https://imgur.com/fSWR1rY

Comment: None of those are actual compilation errors that prevent the app from building, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. At the end the application successfully builds.

Comment: Firebase has *tons* of these. There's not much you can do. However, you can take some comfort in the fact that it's a widely-used framework and generally these warnings don't seem to be adversely affecting functionality.

Comment: Hmmm alright. I find it strange that I have had instances of compilations in the past not generating any errors (I had one today), then when I added just one more pod, it started again. Anyway, I guess this answers my question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change to pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '~> 7.0-beta' and run `pod update`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64671117/556617.

Firebase 6.x does not support the M1 simulator and Firebase 7.x started requiring the Swift extension pods to be explicitly specified with their beta version. Adding the version will enable you to update to Firebase 7.x along with M1 support.

Comment: Thanks, it did update successfully but I'm still getting the same 103 errors.