# Another 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found Question - SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, swiftui, cocoapods

Update Edit: The build will run on a real device but when trying on a simulator I still get these errors.

Im stuck and get figure out what to do. Ive been googling this for 2 days now and have tried every solution I can find. Everything was working fine then one time I went to run my app I stated getting the

- 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found

and

- SignInWithAppleCoordinator.swift:13:8: Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'

errors.

Im stuck...

here is my pod file, do you see anything wrong with it? Mind you everything was working fine at one point with this.

Im using xcode 12.5, pod version 1.10.1.  Yes Im opening the workspace and I've cleared, deleted, reinstalled the pods to no avail.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Draft Order' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Draft Order

   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Firebase/Auth'
   pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
   pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
   pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- Missing `platform` line. Firebase currently requires at least iOS 10.0
- Missing version specification for FirebaseFirestoreSwift. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64671117/556617

Comment: tried that, uncommented and changed platform to ios 10 and added pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '8.2.0-beta'   still getting the same issues.

Comment: There is likely something unusual about the your environment. If you can share a reproducible example, I would take a deeper look.

Answer (score 0):

After messing with this for a couple days the only thing that I got to work for me was to remove my pods using $ pod deintegrate. I deleted the workspace and pod files. Then re-added everything through swifts package dependencies

File → Swift Packages → Add Package Dependency

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git